# Chain rule definition for $f=f(x,g(x,y))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

Here I have a question related to chain rule:

Apply the chain rule to calculate:

$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \quad$ here $\quad\ f=f(x,g(x,y)) $

I have a trouble in the the first member of F because I don't know how to write correctly.

if x was another fuction like h(x,y), then $\ f=f(h(x,y),g(x,y)) $ i write:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} $$

but no. how to write correctly

$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} $ where $\ f=f(x,g(x,y)) $

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ instead of $\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x^2}$? Because the latter doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @JavierBadia Yes! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use total differential concept such as (by skipping dy)
$$df(x,g(x,y))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d f}{d x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$
and for second order
$$d^2f(x,g(x,y))=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(dx)^2+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial g^2}\bigg(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dx\bigg)^2+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(dx)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d^2 f}{d x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial g^2}\bigg(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\bigg)^2+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You know the formula for $f = f(h(x,y),g(x,y))$. Simply replace $h(x,y) = x$ and you should be done.

Comment: Yes, but i think that this is not correct:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} $$

Comment: may be this? 

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} $$

then, 

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} $$